# Simplifying or approximating $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1 - \left(1 - 2^{-k}\right)^n\right)$?

Tags: summation, computer-science, expected-value, order-statistics

Consider a game in which you flip a coin until you flip tails. Your score is then the number of heads you flipped. So, for example, the sequence $H$, $H$, $H$, $T$ has a score of three, while the sequence $T$ has score zero. You play this game $n$ times. Let $X$ denote your maximum score in the game. I'd like to know what $E[X]$ looks like as a function of $n$.

Here's what I know so far. The probability that your score is greater than or equal to some number $k$ is equal to $$\left(1 - \left(1 - 2^{-k}\right)^n\right),$$ which is the probability that you don't have all scores strictly below $k$. We can then write $E[X]$ as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
E[X] & = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} k \cdot Pr[X = k] \\
     & = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} Pr[X \ge k] \\
     & = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(1 - \left(1 - 2^{-k}\right)^n\right).
\end{aligned}$$

At this point, I'm completely out of my league in terms of sequence manipulations, and I'm not sure how to simplify this or even interpret what this looks like.

I know that I can write

$$(1 - 2^{-k})^n = ((1 - 2^{-k})^{2^{k}})^{n 2^{-k}} \approx e^{-n 2^{-k}},$$

which lets me rewrite the sum as being (approximately)

$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (1 - e^{-n 2^{-k}}),$$

but (1) I don't know how much this messes up the estimate and (2) I still have no idea how to simplify or manipulate this sum.

I know that for $n \ll 2^k$ that the term in the sum is close to 0 and that for $n \gg 2^k$ the term in the sum is close to 1, so I'm expecting this sum to come out to something like $\alpha \log_2 n + o(\log_2 n)$ or something like that, but I'm not sure how to rigorously quantify this.

Is there a nice way to simplify this sum or otherwise get a decent approximation of it?

(Context: I'm teaching the [HyperLogLog estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog) and while the full analysis is way too complex to put into a lecture, I'd still like to give some intuitions as to why it works. The game discussed here is equivalent to looking at leading zeros in a random hash, and the distribution of the maximum score is useful for analyzing the expected value of a simple estimator.)

Comment: Did you try using the binomial theorem?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here, but I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: @Jonah Hmm, I hadn't thought to try that. I suspect that manipulating the resulting sum is way above my level of expertise in this area, unfortunately. :-(

Comment: @DavidG.Stork : The requested sum is increasing in $n$, so is unlikely to be $\frac{1}{2^n -1}$.

Comment: Applying binomial theorem, changing summation order and using geometric series you can get this as a finite sum on $n$ terms. The sum seems to be about of size $2^n$, but I am not exactly sure how to simplify it, or even if it can be simplified.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/26214/683666

Comment: I got a much better closed formula than my original: $$E(X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1}\dfrac{\binom n i }{2^i-1}$$

Comment: I did some asymptotic analysis [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3269979).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is a transition in the sum around $k=\log_2n$ as the OP points out, let's define $y=\log_2n-\log_2\log n$ and $z=\log_2n+\log_2\log_2n$. We have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{1\le k\le y} (1 - (1 - 2^{-k})^n) &\ge (y-1)(1-(1-2^{-y})^n) \\
&= (y-1)(1-(1-\tfrac{\log_e n}n)^n) \\
&= (y-1)(1-(e^{(\log_e n)/n})^n) = (y-1)(1-\tfrac1n).
\end{align*}
On the other hand, using $(1-t)^n \ge 1-tn$ for $0\le t\le 1$, we also have
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k>z} (1 - (1 - 2^{-k})^n) &\le \sum_{k>z} n2^{-k} < n2^{1-z} = \frac2{\log_2 n}.
\end{align*}
Therefore the entire series is at least $y(1-\tfrac1n)-1 = \log_2n+O(\log_2\log n)$ and at most $z + \frac2{\log_2n} = \log_2n+O(\log_2\log n)$ as well.

Comment: Oh, that's beautiful. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the mathematical "trick" to this method isn't really a trick at all in hindsight: you already knew that the summand is close to $1$ when $k$ is small and close to $0$ when $k$ is large, and this answer just changed those qualitative observations to quantitative ones: *how* close, *how* small/large :)

Answer (score 3):

Using @Mike Spivey's answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26167/expectation-of-the-maximum-of-i-i-d-geometric-random-variables/26214#26214)
$$E_n = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (1 - (1-q^k)^n)$$
$$\int_0^{\infty} (1 - (1 - q^x)^n) dx \leq E_n \leq 1 + \int_0^{\infty} (1 - (1 - q^x)^n) dx$$ for $q=\frac 12$ we have
$$\frac{n (\psi (n)+\gamma )+1}{n \log (2)}\leq E_n \leq 1 +\frac{n (\psi (n)+\gamma )+1}{n \log (2)}$$

So, almost exact
$$\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} \left(1 - \left(1 - 2^{-k}\right)^n\right)\sim \frac{n H_{n-1}+1}{n \log (2)}-\frac{1}{2}$$

For example, for $n=50$, the xact value is
$5.9909779$ while the approximation gives $5.9909812$.

Comment: Technically, the constants $1,\frac{-1}{2}$ don't affect $\sim.$ It's much closer than $\sim.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I give an asymptotic approximation and a reference on its solution here [Asymptotic equivalent of $\sum_{k=1} ^N\binom{N}{k}\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{1-p^k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2698994/asymptotic-equivalent-of-sum-k-1-n-binomnk-frac-1k11-pk/2808294#2808294)

Plug in $p=1/2 $ in the following:

$$ \sum_{k=0}^\infty \big(1-(1-p^k)^n \big) \sim \frac{\log{n} + \gamma}{\log{(1/p)}} + 1/2, \quad 0<p<1 $$

Comment: What is the error? $\gamma$ and $\frac12$ are irrelevant for $\sim.$ Also, this doesn’t agree with my data that hints $$E(X_n)-\log_2(n)<\frac12$$

Comment: Okay, when $p=1/2,$ I get, from data alone. that you should change $+\frac12$ to  $-\frac{1}{2}.$  In particular, in my data, the difference is in the range of $0.333$ for large $n,$ and $$\frac{\lambda}{\log 2}-\frac{1}{2}\approx 0.3327.$$

Comment: Oh, I think I see your error. The expected value you've gotten is for the maximum number of tosses, not the maximum number of heads, which over-counts by $1.$ Specifically,  your sum really is $k=0$ on the last line, but the actual question starts at $k=1.$

Comment: For what it's worth, with the $-1$ fix, the difference between your approximation and actual data is less than $1/n$ for $n=1$ to $20,000.$

Answer (score 1):

Easier approach than my first answer.

If $X_n$ is your maximum win in $n$ plays, then:

$$\begin{align}P(X_n=m)&=\left(1-\frac1{2^{m+1}}\right)^n-\left(1-\frac1{2^m}\right)^n\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}\binom n i \left(\frac1{2^{mi}}-\frac1{2^{(m+1)i}}\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}\binom n i \left(1-\frac1{2^i}\right)\frac1{2^{mi}}
\end{align}$$

So $$\begin{align}E(X_n)&=\sum_{m=0}^\infty m P(X_n=m)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1}\binom n i \left(1-\frac1{2^i}\right)\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac{m}{2^{mi}}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i -1}\binom n i (1-2^{-i})\frac{2^{-i }}{(1-2^{-i})^2}\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^n (-1)^{i-1}\binom n i \frac{1}{2^i-1}
\end{align}$$

If the coin has probability $p$ of getting heads, then the expected value is:

$$E(X_n)=\sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i-1}\binom n i \frac{p^i}{1-p^i}$$

---

**Examples**

$$\frac{2}{1}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac 53\tag{n=2}$$
$$\frac{3}{1}-\frac{3}{3}+\frac{1}{7}=\frac{15}7\tag{n=3}$$
$$\frac{4}1-\frac{6}{3}+\frac{4}{7}-\frac1{15}=\frac{263}{105}\tag{n=4}$$
$$\frac{5}1-\frac{10}{3}+\frac{10}7-\frac5{15}+\frac1{31}=\frac{1819}{651}\tag{n=5}$$

---

From the data in this table (generated by a python script using infinite precision rationals to compute $E(X_n)$ and then converting to floats,) we see that for $n$ large, it seems $E(X_{2n})\approx 1+E(X_n).$ So it would appear that $c+\log_2 n$ is a good approximation, for large $n.$  $E(X_{n})-\log_2(n)$ appears positive for $n$ and decreasing.

More computations gives me: $E(X_{10000})-\log_2(10000)\approx 0.3328.$

So $E(X_n)-\log_2 n$ seems to be decreasing for all $n$ and bounded below, unclear by what, but it appears a positive value.

I think the accepted answer has a sign wrong. It is best predicted by:

$$\log_2(n)+\frac{\lambda}{\log 2} \color{red}{\mathbf -}\frac{1}{2}$$

Because $\frac{\lambda}{\log 2}-\frac{1}{2}\approx 0.3327$ is very close to what I'm seeing in data.

$$\begin{array}{|r|r|r|}
\hline
n&E(X_n)&E(X_n)-\log_2(n)\\ \hline
1 & 1.000  & 1.000\\ \hline
2 & 1.667  & 0.667\\ \hline
3 & 2.143  & 0.558\\ \hline
4 & 2.505  & 0.505\\ \hline
5 & 2.794  & 0.472\\ \hline
6 & 3.035  & 0.450\\ \hline
7 & 3.241  & 0.433\\ \hline
8 & 3.421  & 0.421\\ \hline
9 & 3.581  & 0.411\\ \hline
10 & 3.726  & 0.404\\ \hline
11 & 3.857  & 0.397\\ \hline
12 & 3.977  & 0.392\\ \hline
13 & 4.088  & 0.388\\ \hline
14 & 4.191  & 0.384\\ \hline
15 & 4.287  & 0.380\\ \hline
16 & 4.377  & 0.377\\ \hline
17 & 4.462  & 0.375\\ \hline
18 & 4.542  & 0.372\\ \hline
19 & 4.618  & 0.370\\ \hline
20 & 4.690  & 0.369\\ \hline
21 & 4.759  & 0.367\\ \hline
22 & 4.825  & 0.365\\ \hline
23 & 4.887  & 0.364\\ \hline
24 & 4.948  & 0.363\\ \hline
25 & 5.005  & 0.361\\ \hline
26 & 5.061  & 0.360\\ \hline
27 & 5.114  & 0.359\\ \hline
28 & 5.166  & 0.358\\ \hline
29 & 5.215  & 0.357\\ \hline
30 & 5.264  & 0.357\\ \hline
31 & 5.310  & 0.356\\ \hline
32 & 5.355  & 0.355\\ \hline
33 & 5.399  & 0.355\\ \hline
34 & 5.441  & 0.354\\ \hline
35 & 5.483  & 0.353\\ \hline
36 & 5.523  & 0.353\\ \hline
37 & 5.562  & 0.352\\ \hline
38 & 5.600  & 0.352\\ \hline
39 & 5.637  & 0.351\\ \hline
40 & 5.673  & 0.351\\ \hline
41 & 5.708  & 0.350\\ \hline
42 & 5.742  & 0.350\\ \hline
43 & 5.776  & 0.349\\ \hline
44 & 5.809  & 0.349\\ \hline
45 & 5.841  & 0.349\\ \hline
46 & 5.872  & 0.348\\ \hline
47 & 5.903  & 0.348\\ \hline
48 & 5.933  & 0.348\\ \hline
49 & 5.962  & 0.347\\ \hline
50 & 5.991  & 0.347\\ \hline
51 & 6.019  & 0.347\\ \hline
52 & 6.047  & 0.347\\ \hline
53 & 6.074  & 0.346\\ \hline
54 & 6.101  & 0.346\\ \hline
55 & 6.127  & 0.346\\ \hline
56 & 6.153  & 0.346\\ \hline
57 & 6.178  & 0.345\\ \hline
58 & 6.203  & 0.345\\ \hline
59 & 6.228  & 0.345\\ \hline
60 & 6.252  & 0.345\\ \hline
61 & 6.275  & 0.345\\ \hline
62 & 6.299  & 0.344\\ \hline
63 & 6.321  & 0.344\\ \hline
64 & 6.344  & 0.344\\ \hline
65 & 6.366  & 0.344\\ \hline
66 & 6.388  & 0.344\\ \hline
67 & 6.410  & 0.343\\ \hline
68 & 6.431  & 0.343\\ \hline
69 & 6.452  & 0.343\\ \hline
70 & 6.472  & 0.343\\ \hline
71 & 6.493  & 0.343\\ \hline
72 & 6.513  & 0.343\\ \hline
73 & 6.532  & 0.343\\ \hline
74 & 6.552  & 0.342\\ \hline
75 & 6.571  & 0.342\\ \hline
76 & 6.590  & 0.342\\ \hline
77 & 6.609  & 0.342\\ \hline
78 & 6.627  & 0.342\\ \hline
79 & 6.646  & 0.342\\ \hline
80 & 6.664  & 0.342\\ \hline
81 & 6.681  & 0.342\\ \hline
82 & 6.699  & 0.342\\ \hline
83 & 6.716  & 0.341\\ \hline
84 & 6.734  & 0.341\\ \hline
85 & 6.751  & 0.341\\ \hline
86 & 6.767  & 0.341\\ \hline
87 & 6.784  & 0.341\\ \hline
88 & 6.800  & 0.341\\ \hline
89 & 6.817  & 0.341\\ \hline
90 & 6.833  & 0.341\\ \hline
91 & 6.848  & 0.341\\ \hline
92 & 6.864  & 0.341\\ \hline
93 & 6.880  & 0.340\\ \hline
94 & 6.895  & 0.340\\ \hline
95 & 6.910  & 0.340\\ \hline
96 & 6.925  & 0.340\\ \hline
97 & 6.940  & 0.340\\ \hline
98 & 6.955  & 0.340\\ \hline
99 & 6.969  & 0.340\\ \hline
100 & 6.984  & 0.340\\ \hline
101 & 6.998  & 0.340\\ \hline
102 & 7.012  & 0.340\\ \hline
103 & 7.026  & 0.340\\ \hline
104 & 7.040  & 0.340\\ \hline
105 & 7.054  & 0.340\\ \hline
106 & 7.067  & 0.340\\ \hline
107 & 7.081  & 0.339\\ \hline
108 & 7.094  & 0.339\\ \hline
109 & 7.108  & 0.339\\ \hline
110 & 7.121  & 0.339\\ \hline
111 & 7.134  & 0.339\\ \hline
112 & 7.147  & 0.339\\ \hline
113 & 7.159  & 0.339\\ \hline
114 & 7.172  & 0.339\\ \hline
115 & 7.184  & 0.339\\ \hline
116 & 7.197  & 0.339\\ \hline
117 & 7.209  & 0.339\\ \hline
118 & 7.221  & 0.339\\ \hline
119 & 7.234  & 0.339\\ \hline
120 & 7.246  & 0.339\\ \hline
121 & 7.258  & 0.339\\ \hline
122 & 7.269  & 0.339\\ \hline
123 & 7.281  & 0.339\\ \hline
124 & 7.293  & 0.339\\ \hline
125 & 7.304  & 0.339\\ \hline
126 & 7.316  & 0.338\\ \hline
127 & 7.327  & 0.338\\ \hline
128 & 7.338  & 0.338\\ \hline
129 & 7.350  & 0.338\\ \hline
130 & 7.361  & 0.338\\ \hline
131 & 7.372  & 0.338\\ \hline
132 & 7.383  & 0.338\\ \hline
133 & 7.393  & 0.338\\ \hline
134 & 7.404  & 0.338\\ \hline
135 & 7.415  & 0.338\\ \hline
136 & 7.426  & 0.338\\ \hline
137 & 7.436  & 0.338\\ \hline
138 & 7.446  & 0.338\\ \hline
139 & 7.457  & 0.338\\ \hline
140 & 7.467  & 0.338\\ \hline
141 & 7.477  & 0.338\\ \hline
142 & 7.488  & 0.338\\ \hline
143 & 7.498  & 0.338\\ \hline
144 & 7.508  & 0.338\\ \hline
145 & 7.518  & 0.338\\ \hline
146 & 7.528  & 0.338\\ \hline
147 & 7.537  & 0.338\\ \hline
148 & 7.547  & 0.338\\ \hline
149 & 7.557  & 0.338\\ \hline
150 & 7.566  & 0.338\\ \hline
151 & 7.576  & 0.338\\ \hline
152 & 7.585  & 0.337\\ \hline
153 & 7.595  & 0.337\\ \hline
154 & 7.604  & 0.337\\ \hline
155 & 7.614  & 0.337\\ \hline
156 & 7.623  & 0.337\\ \hline
157 & 7.632  & 0.337\\ \hline
158 & 7.641  & 0.337\\ \hline
159 & 7.650  & 0.337\\ \hline
160 & 7.659  & 0.337\\ \hline
161 & 7.668  & 0.337\\ \hline
162 & 7.677  & 0.337\\ \hline
163 & 7.686  & 0.337\\ \hline
164 & 7.695  & 0.337\\ \hline
165 & 7.703  & 0.337\\ \hline
166 & 7.712  & 0.337\\ \hline
167 & 7.721  & 0.337\\ \hline
168 & 7.729  & 0.337\\ \hline
169 & 7.738  & 0.337\\ \hline
170 & 7.746  & 0.337\\ \hline
171 & 7.755  & 0.337\\ \hline
172 & 7.763  & 0.337\\ \hline
173 & 7.772  & 0.337\\ \hline
174 & 7.780  & 0.337\\ \hline
175 & 7.788  & 0.337\\ \hline
176 & 7.796  & 0.337\\ \hline
177 & 7.804  & 0.337\\ \hline
178 & 7.813  & 0.337\\ \hline
179 & 7.821  & 0.337\\ \hline
180 & 7.829  & 0.337\\ \hline
181 & 7.837  & 0.337\\ \hline
182 & 7.844  & 0.337\\ \hline
183 & 7.852  & 0.337\\ \hline
184 & 7.860  & 0.337\\ \hline
185 & 7.868  & 0.337\\ \hline
186 & 7.876  & 0.337\\ \hline
187 & 7.883  & 0.337\\ \hline
188 & 7.891  & 0.337\\ \hline
189 & 7.899  & 0.337\\ \hline
190 & 7.906  & 0.337\\ \hline
191 & 7.914  & 0.337\\ \hline
192 & 7.921  & 0.336\\ \hline
193 & 7.929  & 0.336\\ \hline
194 & 7.936  & 0.336\\ \hline
195 & 7.944  & 0.336\\ \hline
196 & 7.951  & 0.336\\ \hline
197 & 7.958  & 0.336\\ \hline
198 & 7.966  & 0.336\\ \hline
199 & 7.973  & 0.336\\ \hline
200 & 7.980  & 0.336\\ \hline
\end{array}
$$